# How to loop through each document in a folder and update the Date Modified

Tags: vbscript, automation

This is what I have so far - 
It opens excel and word, but does not update the times. Is just saving the file enough to update the times?

```
strComputer="."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

'ENTER FILE PATH TO ROOT DIRECTORY HERE Win32_Directory.Name='C:\___________'
Set colFileList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Directory.Name='C:\'} Where ResultClass = CIM_DataFile")


Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = TRUE
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
For Each objFile In colFileList
If objFile.Extension = "xls" Or objFile.Extension = "xlsx" Then
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Name)
    objWorkbook.Save()
    objExcel.Quit
ElseIf objFile.Extension = "doc" or objFile.Extension = "docx" Then
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(objFile.Name)
    objDoc.Save(objFile.Name)
    objWord.Quit
End If
Next
```

Comment: Why are you quitting/exiting the app after the first workbook/document you find? Maybe you should use `objWorkbook.Close` instead of `objExcel.Quit` and `objDoc.Close` instead of `objWord.Quit`.

Comment: I get an 'object doesn't support this property or method' error

Comment: Then you must have typed it wrong.

Comment: That worked! I did type it wrong. Thanks!!